# Mailing Address Verification, Etc. Get County from Zip

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api, geolocation, validation

It seems fairly common today for websites to perform some address verification behind the scenes.  For example, the 4 digit extension on zip codes is commonly filled in.  In addition to filling in the 4 digit zip code extension, I would like to know what county the address belongs to.

This will be utilized in an ASP.NET 3.5 application that already has all the hooks in place for ASP.NET AJAX along with jQuery.

What services out there would allow for this to be done?  Web services, 3rd party includes, etc.

**UI Structure**

```
ADDRESS_LINE1
ADDRESS_LINE2
CITY
STATE 
ZIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got cash, [NetAddress](http://www.softwarecompany.com/dotnet/netaddress.htm) is built for .NET.

It's also been asked on SO before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682093/address-validation-api).

Comment: NetAddress doesn't appear to include county (I still haven't found one that includes county).

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but if it can help someone, then my time was well spent.  It sounds like what you are looking for can be accomplished in two ways.

1 - If you just want to append the county, based on the address, you can do this with a simple ZIP Code/County database.

2 - If you want to standardize the address, verify it, and then add the county to it, you'll need a service that provides frequently updated USPS data.  This is part of our standard address verification API called LiveAddress.  [LiveAddress](http://www.qualifiedaddress.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/)

I work for an address verification company called qualifiedaddress.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenChild() {
    var Area = document.getElemenenter code heretById('<%=ddlArea.ClientID %>');
    var City = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCity.ClientID %>');
    var State = document.getElementById('<%=ddlstate.ClientID %>');
    var Country = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountryName.ClientID %>');
    if (Area.value != "" && City.value != "" && State.value != "" && Country.value != "") {
    var MyArgs = new Array(Area.options[Area.selectedIndex].text,
    City.options[City.selectedIndex].text,
    State.options[State.selectedIndex].text,
    Country.options[Country.selectedIndex].text);
    var WinSettings = "center:yes;resizable:no;dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:900px;"
    // ALTER BELOW LINE - supply correct URL for Child Form
    var MyArgs = window.showModalDialog("http://YourURL/GoogleMapLocationSelector.aspx?Area=" + MyArgs[0].toString() + "&City=" + MyArgs[1].toString() + "&State=" + MyArgs[2].toString() + "&Country=" + MyArgs[3].toString(), MyArgs, WinSettings);

    if (MyArgs == null) {
    window.alert("Error occurred while setting geo location.");
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('<%=txtLongitude.ClientID %>').value = MyArgs[0].toString();
    document.getElementById('<%=txtLatitude.ClientID %>').value = MyArgs[1].toString();
    document.getElementById('<%=hfLatitude.ClientID %>').value = MyArgs[1].toString();
    document.getElementById('<%=hfLongitude.ClientID %>').value = MyArgs[0].toString();
    }
    }
    else {
    alert("Plz Select Area/City/State");
    return false;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The US Postal Service's website [lists many](http://www.usps.com/business/addressverification/welcome.htm) address verification services.[Publication 28](http://pe.usps.com/cpim/ftp/pubs/Pub28/pub28.pdf) (PDF) is the addressing standard for US addresses. Unfortunately, it's more complicated than your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the license option  you need [UPS](http://www.ups.com/e_comm_access/usaddvalidation?loc=en_US) can be free.

Comment: Note that the UPS Address Validation API limits usage to only those applications which intend to deliver packages through UPS.  Although free, it can't be used solely to clean an address during data entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are many services. We perform our shipping through FedEx so we use their "Address Validation Service". The wrapper code to their API in python can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fedex/). The manual from FedEx can fe found [here](http://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/Aug13/AddressChecker_WSDL_Guide.pdf).

The are others like [minfraud](https://www.maxmind.com/en/minfraud-services). You can pass fields such as shipping and billing address, phone numbers, emails, ip address, etc.. See more [here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/minfraud-services).  Based on the provided information, you will get a response that looks like this:

`distance=0;countryMatch=Yes;countryCode=US;freeMail=No;anonymousProxy=No;binMatch=NA;binCountry=;err=;proxyScore=0.00;ip_region=CA;ip_city=Mountain View;ip_latitude=37.3860;ip_longitude=-122.0838;binName=;ip_isp=Google;ip_org=Google;binNameMatch=NA;binPhoneMatch=NA;binPhone=;custPhoneInBillingLoc=;highRiskCountry=No;queriesRemaining=4408;cityPostalMatch=;shipCityPostalMatch=;maxmindID=JBRH7OXI;ip_asnum=AS15169 Google Inc.;ip_userType=business;ip_countryConf=70;ip_regionConf=13;ip_cityConf=10;ip_postalCode=94040;ip_postalConf=;ip_accuracyRadius=999;ip_netSpeedCell=Corporate;ip_metroCode=807;ip_areaCode=650;ip_timeZone=America/Los_Angeles;ip_regionName=California;ip_domain=;ip_countryName=United States;ip_continentCode=NA;ip_corporateProxy=No;riskScore=34.0;prepaid=;minfraud_version=1.3;service_level=standard`

MinFraud AVS check is more geared towards figuring out if a customer that is conducting business on your site is trustworthy.