# How to determine if address doesn't exists in Google Maps Api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Hi I'm trying to find out if an address exists in a City+Province+Country using google's maps API v3 geocoding webservice. I've seen that Google always returns something. For example, if I try to find an existing address: "Colon 100, Córdoba, Córdoba, Argentina" using: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Colon%20100%20,C%C3%B3rdoba,C%C3%B3rdoba,Argentina&sensor=false I get a something. But when I try to find and non existing address like, "nonexistingaddres 2, Córdoba, Córdoba, Argentina" using : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=nonexistingaddress%20100,C%C3%B3rdoba,C%C3%B3rdoba,Argentina&sensor=false I also get a result. I'dont know how to find out if "nonexisting" street exists or not by just analyzing the google's response.
Thanks in advance, Mono.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Address validation using Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682093/address-validation-using-google-maps-api)

Comment: I'm not trying to actually validate and address. I don't want to show any result because Google didn't find the correct street. If street doesn't exists then I don't want to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Maps API v3 geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is not an address validator.  Its purpose is to find the best coordinates for a given (postal) address.

That doesn't stop people from [trying to use it](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+API+3+address+validation)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I figured I'd answer it anyway for people still looking. The best way to handle this in my experience is to look at the API response. I don't use Google Maps for address verification, just for finding coordinates, but I need to fail properly if the address someone has provided isn't valid (at least as far as Google is concerned), since it won't return usable latitude/longitude for my app to consume.

In PHP, I do something like this:

```
   public static function  latlong($location) {

        if ($location!='') {
            try {
                $json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($location));
                $parsedjson = json_decode($json, true);

                if (key_exists(0,$parsedjson['results'])) {
                    $lat_long_array = $parsedjson['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
                    return $lat_long_array;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                //echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
```

Hope that helps any Googlers who end up here.